# Javascript promises - multiple return callbacks

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Parse.com. There are many drills inside each package and many packages in each category.

I'm stuck on .then(function(result, result2, result3) on the last line. The promise can have multiple promises and it is variable. Is there a way to get write something like:

```
.then(function(multipleResults);
console.log(mulitpleResults);
```

Thanks!

```html
var Parse = require('parse/node').Parse;
var _ = require('underscore');

var TrainingPackage = Parse.Object.extend("TrainingPackage");
var TrainingCategory = Parse.Object.extend("TrainingCategory");   

var query2 = new Parse.Query(TrainingPackage);
var query = new Parse.Query(TrainingCategory);

query.equalTo("objectId", "kfHnYdd3T1");

query.find().then(function(cat){
 
 query2.equalTo("category_id", cat[0]);
 return query2.find();

}).then(function(results){

 var promises = [];

   _.each(results, function(result) {

     var Drill = Parse.Object.extend("Drill");
     var query3 = new Parse.Query(Drill);
   
   query3.equalTo("package_id", result);

     promises.push(query3.find());

    });
    
   return Parse.Promise.when(promises);

}).then(function(result, result2, result3){

 console.log(result);
 console.log(result2);
 console.log(result3);


});
```

Comment: Yes, so I used Promise.all and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the inherent nature of a promise it may only resolve to a single value. This being said what you probably want to do is take a look at the [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) API. `Promise.all` will create a new Promise from an array of promises and it will resolve when all your promises are resolved. E.g.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(results) {
    // Both promise1 and promise 2 resolved and available at variable results
})
```

Working example from Mozilla Promise API:

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, "foo");
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(function(values) { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```